# proper way to validate user requests via JWT token

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, jwt, token

In all of my express node routes that require a logged in user, the initial middleware is a function that decodes the JWT token.

But after the token is decoded, it then grabs the `_id` or `email` stored in the token and further makes an API call to my database provider, mongoDB, and tries to find the user corresponding to the `_id` or `email`.

This means that each time a user makes a request I have to query the database for the user's existence. Just decoding the JWT isn't enough because what if the user has been deleted, etc.?

Is this the proper scheme to validate users via JWT token?

Answer (score 1):

There is no one generic solution to this, but this should work for most of the basic cases:

1. Track your user's sessions, using some persistent storage like MongoDB or Redis.
2. Assuming it's MongoDB. You can have a `sessions` collection, where you can store `{ userId, token }` document.
3. Now, whenever a user makes a request, check whether the token has expired or not, if it has expired, delete all docs from the collection, having this token. Otherwise check, whether a session with that token exists or not. If it doesn't, throw an error.
4. When a user gets deleted, delete all the sessions for that user, using `userId`. So, if that user again makes any request it will fail in the middleware since the session object is absent.

Comment: By persistent storage, do you mean the collection always lives in RAM? Is the collection stored in my backend server or on MongoDB's server?

Comment: On MongoDB's server

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom claims question. Start by designing a logical claims principal for the backend component. The most secure designs make all claims available to the backend in a JWT, yet avoid revealing them to the browser. In some cases, you may have reasons for not including all claims in the JWT:

- Perhaps you have concerns about returning JWTs containing personal data to the browser
- Perhaps the authorization server doesn't support issuing the claims from your own data

In such cases you can [look up custom claims](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authorizer.ts#L29) the first time a token is received, then cache results for subsequent requests with the same token. The code is a little tricky but it is easy to manage and prevents too many database hits. More importantly, it can set up your code in a good way, so that the data needed for [authorization](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/logic/services/companyService.ts) is readily available to your business logic.

From a lifetime viewpoint, this is how JWTs are meant to work. Applications use values from the JWT until it expires. If you have concerns about deleted users, use short lived JWTs or reduce the time to live for cached claims.